# How to convert unicode to ascii in JavaScript or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, unicode

I have an app that one of my users uses some kind of custom keyboard that changes the fonts they typed.

They entered these characters to the app searchbox.

I believe this is unicode characters? Correct me If I'm wrong.

The word then gets converted to query params.

```
?search=%F0%9D%99%88%F0%9D%99%96%F0%9D%99%A2%F0%9D%99%AE%F0%9D%99%A5%F0%9D%99%A4%F0%9D%99%A0%F0%9D%99%A4
```

and the server returns no result.

How to change the characters back to regular ascii "Mamypoko" so that my apps show desired result, regardless of user's keyboard?

I don't mind using JavaScript or PHP, I just need to convert before calling MySQL query.

Comment: That would be a very weird keyboard that enters text like this. These are simply very different characters, which the user would have to deliberately choose, or use some online converter to produce. While it’s a feasible technical question to want to convert those characters into their lookalike plain ASCII equivalents, this probably isn’t a problem to be solved in regular daily use…!?

Comment: @deceze I don't know, the user first entered Mamy words, got no result, and then they tried again with Mamypoko. So I think they use some kind of fancy android keyboard apps. I tried looking for the app but couldn't find it. If it is indeed an app and gaining popularity, then we need to be able to support it, I think...?

Comment: For this particular case, iconv could help you: `iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT",urldecode($search));`

Comment: @user1915746 Thanks, that works. Didn't know about iconv.

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius Welcome! I added it also as answer. Maybe other users are searching for the same thing.

Comment: Unicode is character catalogue (a book that lists every character that exists, gives it a unique number and explains its properties), you cannot type or have Unicode. ASCII is a legacy 7-bit encoding nobody should be using in 2022. I recommend [this classic reading](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) about the subject.

Comment: https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html is a useful tool. Those characters aren’t in a different font, they are just not “letters”, they are mathematical symbols. Quite a lot of people use them because they *look* like letters and it lets them write “formatted” text in environments (like social media) which expect plain text. It’s a very dirty hack through and plays havoc with screen readers and search engines. I’d avoid trying to transliterate them into real letters and encourage your users to use the letters they mean instead.

Comment: Quite frankly, *if* there is some Android keyboard or app that allows the user to type in these characters, that shouldn't be *your* problem. "" is the MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD ITALIC CAPITAL M character. While it looks like an "M" and is related to "M", the input "" has as much to do with "Mamypoko" as if I entered "マミポコ". They're simply different characters. If the user goes around entering text using these characters, they should have no expectation to get results for "Mamypoko". Do you want to worry about [Zalgo](https://www.zalgo.org) next…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case, iconv with the //TRANSLIT flag could help you.
See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

```
$search="%F0%9D%99%88%F0%9D%99%96%F0%9D%99%A2%F0%9D%99%AE%F0%9D%99%A5%F0%9D%99%A4%F0%9D%99%A0%F0%9D%99%A4";

$converted = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", urldecode($search));

var_dump($converted);
```

This gives you:

```
string(8) "Mamypoko"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get a exact result when you use `urldecode()` function in php.

code:

```
$myString= 'https://lamesarv.com?search=%F0%9D%99%88%F0%9D%99%96%F0%9D%99%A2%F0%9D%99%AE%F0%9D%99%A5%F0%9D%99%A4%F0%9D%99%A0%F0%9D%99%A4
';

echo urldecode($myString);
```

result:

```
https://lamesarv.com?search=
```

Comment: What is the issue of my answer?

Comment: I'm not the one downvoting. You misunderstood my question. I'm asking to convert  to Mamypoko with JavaScript or PHP, not how to decode the URL back to .